# recv function in socket programming fails when I am using MSG_WAITALL flag

Tags: sockets, timeout, winsock

I have written a very simple code for client side of a socket.
this is my receive function:

```
    int n32RecvLength = 10;  

    do {   

        n32RecvLength = recv(m_socketConnectSocket, m_szRecvBuffer, m_n32BufferLength, MSG_WAITALL);    

        if ( n32RecvLength > 0 )
        {
            printf("\nBytes received: %d\n", n32RecvLength);
            //for(int i = 0; i< n32RecvLength; i++)
                //putchar(m_szRecvBuffer[i]);

            if (evRecPacket != NULL)
            {
                evRecPacket(static_cast<void*>(m_ptrvDerivedClass),reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(m_szRecvBuffer) , n32RecvLength); 
            }
        }
        else if ( n32RecvLength == 0 ) 
        {  
            printf("Connection closed!!!!!!!\n");
            if(evDisconnected != NULL) 
                evDisconnected(static_cast<void*>(m_ptrvDerivedClass));  
            break;
         }

        else
        {
            int errorNum = WSAGetLastError();  

            if (errorNum == WSAETIMEDOUT)
            {
                printf ("\n timeOut\n");   
                n32RecvLength = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", errorNum);
                if(evDisconnected != NULL) 
                    evDisconnected(static_cast<void*>(m_ptrvDerivedClass));  
                break;
            }
        } 

    } while( n32RecvLength > 0 );
```

and I have initialized it in this function:

```
   WSADATA swsaData;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;

unsigned int n32CheckCondition = 0; 

n32CheckCondition = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &swsaData);
if (n32CheckCondition != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", n32CheckCondition);
    return;
}


ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

char szPortNumber[100];
itoa(m_n32PortNumber,szPortNumber , 10);



n32CheckCondition = getaddrinfo(m_szIpServerAddr, szPortNumber, &hints, & m_ptrsResult);
if ( n32CheckCondition != 0 ) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", n32CheckCondition);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}   

m_socketConnectSocket = socket( m_ptrsResult->ai_family,  m_ptrsResult->ai_socktype,  m_ptrsResult->ai_protocol);
if (m_socketConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}   

// to set timeout feature to your system, uncomment the two following lines and adjust it
DWORD timeout =  10000;  // mili second!
setsockopt(m_socketConnectSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

I am using recv function with MSG_WAITALL flag. I have set the timeout = 10000 milliseconds.
I have set the m_n32BufferLength = 8. when I send a 8-byte data, it works fine, but when I send 9 byte it shows first 8 bytes and after a few second (timeout value) the recv(...) returns zero. I know when recv returns zero, it means that socket has been closed. but I have not closed the socket. and I also loss the 9th byte of my data. 
could you please tell me what I should do?

Comment: You are sending 9 bytes, and asking `recv` to read 8 bytes at a time.  That works fine the first time, because there are 8 bytes available, but the second time around, there is only 1 byte available, and `recv` is waiting for 8 bytes, so it blocks until the timeout elapses, then it fails. That is perfectly normal behavior.

Comment: The *only* way `recv` can return 0 (unless the underlying transport driver is buggy) is if either 1) the peer actually disconnected gracefully (you didn't show the peer's code) or 2) you ask `recv` for 0 bytes. Given the code you have shown, #2 is not likely (unless you have a buffer overflow somewhere), so #1 is the obvious reason, however unlikely you think it is. You will have to debug the peer to find out.

Comment: Also, just a side note, in your loop, the `while( n32RecvLength > 0 )` statement is only ever reached when `n32RecvLength` is > 0, so the statement is always true, so you may as well just use `while (true)` instead, and don't bother re-assigning `n32RecvLength` in the `WSAETIMEDOUT` case.